# How do i cache pages that are created on the fly by java servlet so reusable and indexable

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, web-crawler

Im using Amazon Web Services with Tomcat to deploy a Java application.

The application consists of a a Lucene index of artist data and a website that allows a user to search for a musical artist (e.g madonna, beatles) it will then return information about that artist generated from the index in the form of a html page. The index doesn't change and hence the page generated for a particular artist never changes. I don't want to pre-calculate the pages because that would take a long time (over a million pages) and require alot of space, but I do want the pages to be cached so that:

1. A search for the artist can return existing page instead of having
   to recreate it.
2. I want pages get crawled and indexed by Google so they can be returned in Google search.

How do I go about this (I have plenty of Java experience but not much website experience)

When I say the index never changes I mean that the deployed application uses the same index, and that index is never modified. About once a month a new index will be created and the application redeloyed with the new index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up some cache headers on the pages so the pages are stored for a longer period of time (e.g. a few days), move tomcat over to some other hostname, then setup amazon cloudfront to have tomcat as the origin server.

Then finally setup a CNAME DNS record to point www.yourdomain.com to the cloudfront

When you update your index simply tell cloudfront to invalidate its entire cache.

Thats the laziest way that I can think of to do this. (but I am open to suggestion if there is a lazier way to do this. )

Comment: Thanks, though I hardly understand a word of it. I'm using Elastic Beanstalk and Route53 so can I use Cloudfront with EB or can I do this in EB, can I do it in code I much more comfortable with pure Java solutions

Comment: cloudfront is effectively a frontend cache for any site you specify. it will mirror 'static' files at various locations by sending a query to a webserver only when a request is sent. but you will be stuck with a url like : aadsfasd.cloudfront.net then you can use a CNAME record to redirect that domain name to something more friendly.

Comment: Oh I see so it knows if page already exists and if it does just serves it without even talking to tomcat server, does that mean then when tomcat serves the page for an artist the first time it doesnt need to cache the page itself because it will be cached by Cloudfront itself, or does Cloudfront point to the page cached on the tomcat server ?

Comment: Cloud front will check to see if it has a page already cached ( and if the cache timeout has expired ) and if it doesn't have it it will query the origin server ( in your case tomcat ) for the file . It also has the benefit of having "end points" all around the world as to serve pages faster. And yes cloud front will only query tomcat if it needs to so you won't need to implement any cache features on your tomcat ( although it would be beneficial to set a http header stating that your served page can be cached for x hours or days, for more info about that Google cache control headers )

Comment: Okay great, and will Google index these CloudFront pages or do I have to so something else to get it to do that.

Comment: well you will need someone that is already crawled by google to link to the pages at least once to have google index them.

Comment: If I linked to them from my current site that would work then i guess

Comment: @PaulTaylor Yep, you can check your access logs for when googlebot gets called also.

Comment: Ive just be warned that with CloudFront you can get end up getting an enormous bill, assuming charged per lookup so if targeted, giving me cold feet

Comment: @PaulTaylor This is the case with all amazon web services, You are charged for usage and are provided guarantees (unlike many of the cheaper 'unlimited' hosting providers that rate limit your bandwidth and IO when you use too many resources. ) Cloudfront pricing is based on content throughput, (assuming that you use more then the AWS 'free tier'), and at its 'most expensive' is 8 cents per gig. From a practical perspective I run a site which has streaming video and is fairly content heavy, we run well beyond the free limits of AWS, and our variable costs for data transfer vary by $3 per month

Comment: @PaulTaylor the current pricing structure is here: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/ and the free tier is 50gb / 2 million requests per month.

Comment: So I just set the Original Domain Name to the CNAME of my Route 53 domain that points to EB and I set Object Caching to customize, added another CNAME on Route53 -> CloudFront and set this as an alternate name in Cloudfront  and it worked via this new CNAME (without me having to change anything on EB) :)

Comment: Yep, it seems like you are gaining a grasp on the concepts .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directory for your cache with code like the following in your Servlet and then store your newly generated pages there.

```
       cache = Paths.get(request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir") + "/artists");
        try {
            if(!Files.exists(cache)) {
                Files.createDirectory(cache);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
```

Comment: Ah so my code can just check if page exists and if so return it, if not create it - great that sounds like point 1 answered, now ill these pages get indexed by Google or do I have to do more ?